# Memory overhead of neo4j

Tags: neo4j, jqassistant

What is the disk-memory overhead of neo4j? At jqassistant I analyse 5 MB of Sources and the compiled jar which includes everything is about 50 MB great. The database-directory is about 500 MB. In other words storing the structure information of an application (not the code himself) need 100 or 10 times more space. Is this a usual relation?

Comment: Does the databse directory includes transaction logs as well ?

Comment: I don't know it's complete target\jqassistant\store with a message.log with 7 MB. How can I detect transaction logs? And wouldn't they delete at commit?

Comment: no they are not deleted at commit time. they end up with `transaction.id.*`

Comment: Okay this explains further 330MB. However they are still needed and I assume they will increase if the input size 5Mb or 50MB increase.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed transaction logs take most of the disk space. The problem is that jQAssistant currently uses Neo4j 2.x and (AFAIK) it is not possible to deactivate transaction logs. 
This is possible with Neo4j 3.x, we're currently implementing support for both Neo4j versions. The default setting of jQAssistant will configure Neo4j 3.x to disable the transaction logs as they do not add value to the in the embedded environment.

Comment: this still means that neo4j need 5-50 times more space than the pure data?

Comment: Yes, disk space overhead is quite large, but I'm usually calculating with factor 3, e.g. JRE 1.8 (rt.jar) has a size of 60MB and takes about 200MB as database on disk (without tx logs, including them leads to about 600MB).